# Distinguish between users in HTTP

Tags: http, networking, tcp, network-programming

I have a question about distinguishing user in HTTP.

I opened wireshark and web browser, started wandering in web pages on some known website. and noticed that my PC opened several TCP connections and on each connection there are several HTTP request\response.

My main goal is to identify user that wandering in my website (for example)
at first, I thought of finding matching response for each request but it is not trivial as I have done alot of reading about it. specially if there are several TCP connections for one user.

I also thought of identify user by its source port\ip- but there are several TCP connection for one user and there are more than one user (some of them might be beyond NAT).

So my question is how can I identify\isolate all the http requests\responses from one user given:

1. there are more that one user
2. some of them might connected to NAT
3. each user open several TCP connections for the "main" HTTP request
4. cookies might change during session

Is there some sniffer or library that already has this ability of distinguish between users (this http request\response belongs to that user)?

This process suppose to run on the fly.

Thanks alot.